# Setting draw order of labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, heat-map

We're having an issue trying to display labels UNDER a heatmap-styled layer, and can't figure out why they are always defaulting to the topmost position on the map.

We're using the 'heat map' style instead of using density maps as they are easier and basically the exact same visual representation of a density map.

We're also using the Google-styled SpatiaLite OSM data for our basemaps:

[image]

Is there a setting that controls this that we can't find?

Comment: I believe the only way is to export to Illustrator/inkscape with layers and move the labels layers below the heat map, QGIS will always place labels last (on top by design)

Comment: @Mapperz might as well add that as an answer... no other takers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (from research on the web) the only way is to export to Illustrator/inkscape with layers and move the labels layers below the heat map, QGIS will always place labels last (on top by design).

Suggestion if you have no transparency in any layers you can export to vector pdf and move the draw order for the text (using distiller/Illustrator)

tip
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46265/separate-each-letter-of-a-text-to-its-own-layer